# How to make the recv function in winsock2 stop after a specific time..?

Tags: visual-c++, client-server, windows-8.1, console-application, winsock2

In an developing a Windows Desktop Console Application in c++ in Visual Studio 3013 for Windows Desktop, which acts as a client and tries to connect to a server. Once the Connection with the server is successful, it sends a handshaking signal to the server and waits for a response from the server. Iam using winsocks2 in this application.
The receive function I am using is a blocking call

```
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
```

So until my server sends a response, the client is blocked.
What I need is the client to check for response only for a certain time (say 10 sec). If there is no response within this time frame ,I want the client to disconnect from the server.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Call `setsockopt` on your socket with the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option and a timeout value in milliseconds. For example:

```c
DWORD timeoutMs = 10000;
iResult = setsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, 
        SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeoutMs, sizeof(timeoutMs));
...
```

More details about `setsockopt` on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx